# rawTransaction and contractAddress

Tags: wallets

I was working with ethereum wallet which is connected to my private blockchain. I performed a transaction which included transfer of ether from one account to another. Using the hash of this transaction, I called the `eth.getTransactionReceipt(<tx hash>)` method. It returns a transaction object which has its `contractAddress: null`. I know there is a single wallet contract **Wallet.sol** which does not have a transfer method. So how is this transfer done by the wallet application? Ain't there any contract for this purpose?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transferring funds from an account to another is a base function of Ethereum, you don't need a specific contract to do that.

About the `contractAddress` in the receipt, it is set when the effect of the transaction is the creation of a contract. In any other case it's `null`.

From the [official documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactionreceipt), `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt` returns:

> Object - A transaction receipt object, or null when no receipt was
>   found:
>
> - blockHash: String, 32 Bytes - hash of the block where this    transaction was in.
> - blockNumber: Number - block number where this    transaction was in.
> - transactionHash: String, 32 Bytes - hash of the    transaction.
> - transactionIndex: Number - integer of the transactions    index position in the block.
> - from: String, 20 Bytes - address of the    sender.
> - to: String, 20 Bytes - address of the receiver. null when its    a contract creation transaction.
> - cumulativeGasUsed: Number - The    total amount of gas used when this transaction was executed in the    block.
> - gasUsed: Number - The amount of gas used by this specific    transaction alone.
> - **contractAddress: String - 20 Bytes - The contract    address created, if the transaction was a contract creation,    otherwise
>     null.**
> - logs: Array - Array of log objects, which this    transaction generated.

Comment: I get it that transferring funds is a base function of Ethereum. If ethereum doesn't use a contract for this purpose, then how does it perform this function?

Comment: You can attach value (ether) to any type of TX. Here you can see the parameters you can set for a TX: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#parameters-25 In particular, with `to` field you specify the address that will receive the funds you attached to the TX, so that its balance will be increased by that value and your will be decreased. In a very specific tx, a contract creation, `to` is null but the effect is the same: value is assigned to the balance of the contract if it is correctly created.

Comment: Note that if the transaction involves calling a function in a contract that creates a new contract then contractAddress will also be null.